# how to change manifest in debug folder

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I did clone android project from GitHub and i wanted to change it.
the app got permission for .ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. but there isn't any permission like that.
I searched that permission in the app folder and i found it in another manifest with this path AppName/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug
I tried to remove this permission but when i open project in android studio the permission come back!
what should i do to remove this?
consider there isn't any permission like that in the main manifest in android studio.
[image: permissions in main manifest]
[image: permissions in another debug manifest]

Comment: Should post code in question, not images of code.

Comment: These are my permission in manifest: which one caused location access? 
<permission
        android:name="org.androidcheckup.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="org.androidcheckup.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <!-- Optional permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>

Answer (score 1):

As Code-Apprentice said all the files under the build folder are auto-generated when you compile your app. Editing it won't have any effect, rather you should try to analyse from where this permission is coming!

Manifest is getting merged with libraries and other modules and then merged manifest actually goes into the apk. You can always analyse merged manifest apk by checking "Merged Manifest" tab and click on permission or any components to see from which modules/libraries it is exactly coming!

[image]

Comment: but i want to know which permission caused the location access request?
however i find a simple code to remove permission location:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>

Answer (score 0):

All files under the `build` folder are generated when you compile your app. Editing these files directly will have no effect. Instead, you need to edit the source that these files are generated from. Some of the generated AndroidManifest.xml comes from the `app/build.gradle` file and the rest comes from `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. You should edit these as needed.

Comment: I put this code in manifest and it remove location permission:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>

Comment: @MAHDI Are you asking a question? If so can you please clarify.

Comment: No. It was result and solution for my problem
Thank you